# Google Calendar change event time by typing in new time

Tags: google-calendar

When I create a new event in Google Calendar, it is very easy to type in the time when typing in the description. I can add a new event with a time in about 3-4 seconds, by typing something like "Meet with Steve 7pm-8pm".

However, if I have added an event without a time, and I later want to add a time for the event, I have to perform the following steps:

1. Click the event
2. Click "Edit"
3. Uncheck the "All Day" check box.
4. Drop down the start time listbox
5. Scroll down to the desired start time
6. Click the desired start time
7. Drop down the end time listbox
8. Scroll down to the desired end time
9. Click the desired end time
10. Click "Save"

This takes me about 15 seconds. It's actually faster to delete the original event and re-add it with a time.

Is there a way to change an event's time by typing it in?

I would love to just be able to edit the description and add a time, and have Google Calendar interpret that just like it does when you add a new event. However, it does not do that. It just makes the time you typed in part of the new description.

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no shortcut to do this like the "Quick Add" to create an event.

However, "All Day" shouldn't get automatically checked. I haven't seen it do that. Also, the times are input fields. While you can use the dropdown to pick a pre-configured time, there's nothing to keep you from typing what you need.